# Screen flicker in Ubuntu AMD Laptop

Tags: drivers

I have a Laptop with AMD A6 processor, I installed Ubuntu on it, everything is ok but my screen flickering (blinking), I don't know what's the solution. Before it was a windows laptop there I didn't face any problem like this, I facing this in Linux OS only. Anybody please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.